# Center floating button in vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to center the "BUY NOW" button to be in the middle of the screen, but I can't get it to work.

I have created 3 flex items and added the button to the middle flex. However this didn't work either.

I tried using justify-space-around and justify-space-between but no luck.

```
<v-flex xs12>
  <v-layout row >
    <v-flex ></v-flex>
    <v-flex pt-2>
      <v-card>
          <v-btn
            color="pink"
            dark
            absolute
            top
          >
            BUY NOW
          </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex ></v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-flex>
```

Here is a link for [codepen](https://codepen.io/kidplama/pen/WmExNq)

Please help.

I need the button to be position exactly in the middle like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add some css to Button:

```
<v-btn
  color="pink"
  dark
  absolute
  top
  :style="{left: '50%', transform:'translateX(-50%)'}"
>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Since all values are not dynamic you could go: `style="left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)"`

Comment: Why, in frickin 2022, is it still so hard to just center a button!!!

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ygrrox

I moved the button into another flexbox above the flexbox with the caption. `text-xs-center` moves the text horizontally and `align-center` moves the text vertically. You can see my changes in the codepen :)

```
<v-flex text-xs-center align-center>
    <v-btn
        color="pink"
        dark
        absolute
    > buy now
</v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `text-xs-center` to center button horizontally.

```
<v-card class="text-xs-center">
    <v-btn
      color="pink"
      dark
      absolute
      top
    > buy now </v-btn>
</v-card>
```

Comment: @ittuss  `text-xs-center` doesn't solve it. It puts the beginning of the button in the center of the card, which results in the button being pushed to the right. I have updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/kidplama/pen/oVeEWz)